# How do you find a qualified, reliable technical reviewer for a programming document?

Tags: language-agnostic

I need to find a technical reviewer for a programming document.

I have looked on Craigslist and various freelancers' websites (RentACoder, Odesk, Elance, etc) but it's difficult to determine who is qualified to act as a reviewer.

The last thing I need is to have the document reviewed by someone who either doesn't know what they are talking about or is not willing to go to the trouble of reviewing the document thoroughly.

An ineffective review might be worse than no review at all since it might generate a false sense of completion.

Any tips on selecting someone qualified & reliable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried asking a publisher? (O'Reilly, Manning etc)

Obviously publishers need to find technical reviewers and indeed peer reviewers for a number of topics, so they may well be able to put you in touch with someone. They'll probably suggest that you write a book for them, too.

Comment: Jon: "They'll probably suggest that you write a book for them, too." -> Is the demand for authors so great in the computer book world?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to determine if someone is qualified as a reviewer is to have them show you they can do the job:

1. Ask for a portfolio of previous
   work, or
2. (better) Give them a sample
   of your current project and ask them
   to do a review.

Another option is to ask your contacts for any recommendations.

I strongly advise against relying on a dead-tree (CV/Resume) for making a determination, as it will distract you from weeding out those who "have experience" but cannot do the job, or you can miss finding those who *can* do the job, but lack the experience.

Answer (score 1):

You could look on SO and see if you can find some people that give answers that give you an idea that they know what they are talking about, though this could be a slow process.

I actually like BryanH's second response, let them review something non-critical and see how they do, but have an idea what it important to you.

Are you looking for someone to be able to make decisions as to what you wrote is technically valid, or do you want someone that can also check the writing and see that the grammar is correct, for example?

There are several things to look at when reviewing a document, you should be very specific about what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

### Linkedin

Linkedin is a popular network for pitching contracts to documentation freelancers. It's also a fantastic way to procure interest from full-time technical writers at large organisations that might be looking for side-projects (if allowed), or case study projects to leverage their existing skills on new methods.

### Mailing Lists

Depending on your geographical location, there are also popular mailing lists with a high volume of contract communications (and passionate technical writers). In Australia, the ATW mailing list is a good resource.

### Industry Bodies

If you're in the US, contact the [Society for Technical Communication](http://www.stc.org/). Other nations will have other bodies (or regional chapters).

### Summary

I focus more on the question of "where to find writers" than I do of "how to get a competent peer review", but the right person is always the biggest hurdle. In this way I admit to having a bias in preference for communities of active and engaged participants over something like a bidding website or outsourcing mechanism. The latter is fine, but these islands of technical writers are vocal and active because they are interested, and often give back to the community that makes it available to connect talent to projects such as yours. Good luck!